# Recursion with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

Assume the following table:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c83a/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE entries 
    (
    [entryID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [bOpen] [bit] NULL,
    [nextEntryID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    );

INSERT INTO entries
(entryID, bOpen, nextEntryID)
VALUES
('21572F4C-BA63-489B-9205-AD1451CEE411', 0, NULL),
('FF4ADC83-1270-418B-8E31-FD1AEA2C1ADF', 0, '21572F4C-BA63-489B-9205-AD1451CEE411'),
('7ED7AF83-6595-4848-AFDF-4F7D54889F80', 1, NULL),
('C7AA25D3-B70D-45CB-A143-CF380E6FD0D3', 1, '7ED7AF83-6595-4848-AFDF-4F7D54889F80'),
('ADA3312E-6FF2-4EC6-9FE3-C994D2FCD16F', 1, 'C7AA25D3-B70D-45CB-A143-CF380E6FD0D3'),
('9BE0F5FA-09F0-423C-8173-98AD73522412', 0, NULL),
('5019558E-73FC-4A10-B526-49DB2253B9B9', 1, 'B2EF093A-45B4-4780-A5F5-ECEE02A26274'),
('B2EF093A-45B4-4780-A5F5-ECEE02A26274', 0, NULL)
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from entries
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c83a/1/0)**:

```
|                              ENTRYID | BOPEN |                          NEXTENTRYID |
|--------------------------------------|-------|--------------------------------------|
| 21572F4C-BA63-489B-9205-AD1451CEE411 |     0 |                               (null) |
| FF4ADC83-1270-418B-8E31-FD1AEA2C1ADF |     0 | 21572F4C-BA63-489B-9205-AD1451CEE411 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 7ED7AF83-6595-4848-AFDF-4F7D54889F80 |     1 |                               (null) |
| C7AA25D3-B70D-45CB-A143-CF380E6FD0D3 |     1 | 7ED7AF83-6595-4848-AFDF-4F7D54889F80 |
| ADA3312E-6FF2-4EC6-9FE3-C994D2FCD16F |     1 | C7AA25D3-B70D-45CB-A143-CF380E6FD0D3 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 9BE0F5FA-09F0-423C-8173-98AD73522412 |     0 |                               (null) |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 5019558E-73FC-4A10-B526-49DB2253B9B9 |     1 | B2EF093A-45B4-4780-A5F5-ECEE02A26274 |
| B2EF093A-45B4-4780-A5F5-ECEE02A26274 |     0 |                               (null) |
```

As you may already have noticed, I have a field `nextEntryID`, which contains the linked `entryID`.
I seperated the pairs with hypens in the result.
The most interesting pair would be the two last entries. Both are linked to each other but have a different `bOpen` value (`1` and `0` respectively).

I'd now like to find out all entries/pairs in my table, where the starting entry has `bOpen = 1` and is linked to another entry with `bOpen = 0`.
Theoretically, there can be unlimited entries linked to each other, so I guess we need some kind of recursion in this case?
Or is there another way for this?

Additional info (thanks @david.pfx):

- The structure is like this and I would rather not change the structure, although it would be possible to add changes.
- The "depth" of the linked entries is not fixed at 2 or 3; I'd guess that the depth would not go over 4 most of the times, but it could be possible.
- The `IDs` are globally unique
- Any approach/suggestion would be great

Comment: More problem definition required. Is this data structure rigidly defined, or did you create it? Can you change the structure? Is the depth of linking fixed at 2 or 3, or can it be deeper? Are the IDs globally unique? Are you insistent on an answer that is a single SQL query, or a stored procedure, or algorithmic code?

Comment: @david.pfx See my update above.

Comment: @KumarHarsh Realize what? I am fully aware that the entries i generate with `NEWID()` are getting...a new id. I did that because it just doesn't matter really. I thought that was clear from the question, but it seems to cause confusion, so I'll edit anyway.

Answer (score 0):

not complete.try something like this.

```
declare  @entries TABLE
    ([entryID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,[bOpen] [bit] NULL,[nextEntryID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL
    );

INSERT INTO @entries
(entryID, bOpen, nextEntryID)
VALUES
('21572F4C-BA63-489B-9205-AD1451CEE411', 0, NULL),
('FF4ADC83-1270-418B-8E31-FD1AEA2C1ADF', 0, '21572F4C-BA63-489B-9205-AD1451CEE411'),
('7ED7AF83-6595-4848-AFDF-4F7D54889F80', 1, NULL),
('C7AA25D3-B70D-45CB-A143-CF380E6FD0D3', 1, '7ED7AF83-6595-4848-AFDF-4F7D54889F80'),
('ADA3312E-6FF2-4EC6-9FE3-C994D2FCD16F', 1, 'C7AA25D3-B70D-45CB-A143-CF380E6FD0D3'),
('9BE0F5FA-09F0-423C-8173-98AD73522412', 0, NULL),
('5019558E-73FC-4A10-B526-49DB2253B9B9', 1, 'B2EF093A-45B4-4780-A5F5-ECEE02A26274'),
('B2EF093A-45B4-4780-A5F5-ECEE02A26274', 0, NULL)
--select * from @entries
;With CTE as
(select  a.*,1 rn from @entries a
where a.nextEntryID is not null and a.bopen=1
union all
select e.*,rn+1 from @entries E inner join cte C on c.nextEntryID=e.EntryID  and e.bOpen=0
)

select a.* from cte a
```